# Strange SQL Error: The conversion of a varchar to a datetime resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, windows-server-2008

After installing the application in a fresh server, it's throws off the error:

```
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an 
out-of-range value.
```

the application works properly on other servers so I'm puzzled with this problem. The value being saved is

```
25/4/2012 1:18:01 PM
```

which is a DateTime type already that is being saved into a datetime column so I'm sure there's no problem with the database and the code itself. Could the problem be strictly because of the server's settings?  Any specific reasons and solutions/workaround?

Comment: What is the field type, and how are you accessing it? It sounds too early to be "sure" there's no problem with the code...

Comment: is your sql regional setting use date format dd/mm/yyyy? or mm/dd/yyyy?

Comment: You say it's a DateTime, being saved into a datetime column, and yet the error message is telling us that, *at some point*, it's being converted into a string. You've not shown any code, so we can't point you to the line that's causing the problem. Best guess at this point would be that you're constructing a query string rather than using parameters. Generally, you should keep datetimes *as* datetimes, and rely on e.g. ADO.Net for performing any necessary conversions between the .NET concept and the SQL concept, and avoid ever treating them as strings.

Comment: @ShoaibShaikh - although checking/changing the regional settings may fix the immediate issue, it doesn't address the more worrying aspect - treating datetimes as strings should be avoided entirely.

Comment: yes @Damien_The_Unbeliever SQL injection is a major threat to such system.he should try using DbParameter instead of passing string values to SQL query.

Comment: Parsing to datetime has been done on the silverlight part already. Web service receives the datetime and tries to save it to the database which then throws the exception. On a side note, Injection is impossible since the query is parameterized.

Comment: @shoaib i'll try the regional settings things then. Care to put a more detailed instruction about that?

Comment: @Bahamut - what are the declared types of the parameters? As *is clear* from the error message, SQL Server is being handed a `varchar` by something, and is attempting to convert it to a `datetime`. So *somewhere* along the line, it's being converted into a string.

Comment: @damien parsing the given date with the language set to english results in that error. Same can be aaid when SET dateformat mdy is used. That's why i've concluded this is a sql regional settings error.

Comment: @Bahamut i have added an answer showing how to set dateformat in sql server

Answer (score 1):

A way to prevent the problem.

If you have any influence over the content of a feed with dates in it, 'Day# MonthName 4digityear' is the format you want.  Regardless of regional settings, the heuristics in sql server don't get confused about '25APR2012'.  This is a more robust format.  It will travel over an ocean without trouble.

Otherwise, you have to use convert(datetime, TheDateString, CorrectFormatNumber)

I think 131 might work for you.

Oh, and to echo some comments, If you can prevent this data from taking the form of a string, you should.

Comment: i haven't tested this yet but what could be the reason that it's working on other machines except this specific one i'm installing it on?

Comment: Thanks for this - a sound approach to handling dates.

Comment: Incorrect. `set language Português; select CONVERT(datetime,'25apr2012')` gives an error. The only safe formats are entirely numerical. This is, yet again, a reason to avoid strings in the first place. Safe numerical formats are `yyyymmdd` and `yyyy-mm-ddThh:MM:ss` (where T is the literal letter `T`).

Answer (score 1):

**you can set the datetime format for per connection basis  like**

SET DATEFORMAT dmy

This method allows you use a date format for dates sent to SQL Server of d/m/y, but it is connection dependent. If a new connection is made to SQL Server or if the server is stopped and restarted, the date format goes back to m/d/y.

**Set format permanently**

To set the language on the server you must add a language by using sp_addlanguage. 
The example below sets the language for British English and gives the dates in DD/MM/YY format. The example can also be applied to other countries, but you may need to modify the parameters for sp_addlanguage.

exec sp_addlanguage 'British', 'English',
   'January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,
   November,December',
      'Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec',
   'Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday',
   dmy,1
   sp_configure 'default language', 1
   reconfigure with override

for more information

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/173907

Answer (score 0):

Good suggestions but on my case, i can't bother going through thousands of lines of code. Reinstalling the sql and setting the regional settings during the installation is the quickest and least time consuming way.

Parsing the datetime string on the app before saving it in the database is a given.

Setting the language and dateformat only works for the current query and not for every query made. Surely, updating the sql queries on the code is a waste of time, imo and in my case.